# Storing Exceptions in my webapp?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, directory-structure

Until recently, I've done as shown below to create and throw custom exceptions:

**File:** Myclass.php:

```
namespace myapp\libraries;

class myclass {

    setEmail($email) {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
             throw new myClassException("Email not valid");
        }
    }

}

class myClassException extends \Exception {}
```

Ok, so this works well and are easy to maintain and build upon, provided that custom exceptions *always* exists in the same file and are defined after the class which throws the Exceptions.

**Question: What does current PHP conventions and common sense say?**

Here's the solutions I can think about:

1. Keep declaring custom Exceptions immediately after the class that will invoke/throw it.
2. Store all custom Exceptions in a mutually shared file, called `customExceptions.php`.
3. Store all custom Exceptions in a separate file named after its exception, `myClassException.php`, in a directory called `/exceptions`.

Comment: I too would like an answer to this, but the accepted answer has negative vote so.. I think hgihly custom exceptions belong in the class that throws them, generic exceptions belong in single file. Though this results in lots of files. Most of our exception classes are empty and thrown in one place only, so a whole file for it seems wasteful.

Comment: Single file + aggregator of logs seems like the best thing to do to me, two years after my question was asked.

Comment: Single file for all exceptions? My issue with that is that modular construction of our app (using Symfony) is broken, each module would have dependencies elsewhere (not that we expect to share modules but still).

Comment: Sorry, I was answering what I believed was something completely different. I thought about what I did, and we went for the subfolders solution. It made the most sense. For quick and dirty things, the Exception was placed immediately below the main class in the same file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store all classes separately, one class - one file. Name of class should be name of containing file also (verbatim, case sensitive).
Use namespaces in format "vendor/application/..." - it's VERY handy thing, I promise.
[More about it](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1)